# Swift: Creating an array of UIImage

Tags: ios, arrays, uiimage, swift

Using Swift, I'm trying to create an array of UIImage objects for a simple animation. Contextual help for `animationImages` reads, "The array must contain UI Image objects."

I've tried to create said array as follows, but can't seem to get the syntax correct:

```
var logoImages: UIImage[]
logoImages[0] = UIImage(name: "logo.png")
```

This throws:
! Variable logoImages used before being initialized

Then I tried

```
var logoImages = []
logoImages[0] = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
```

Which throws:
! Cannot assign to the result of this expression

I've checked the docs here, but the context isn't the same:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have two problems (and without a regex!)

### 1. You aren't creating an array. You need to do:

```
var logoImages: [UIImage] = []
```

or

```
var logoImages: Array<UIImage> = []
```

or

```
var logoImages = [UIImage]()
```

or

```
var logoImages = Array<UIImage>()
```

### 2. If you want to add new objects to an array, you should use `Array.append()` or some of the equivalent syntactic sugar:

```
logoImages.append(UIImage(named: "logo.png")!)
```

or

```
logoImages += [UIImage(named: "logo.png")!]
```

or

```
logoImages += [UIImage(named: "logo.png")!, UIImage(named: "logo2.png")!]
```

You need to append to the array because (excerpt [from docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_135)):

> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array. If you try to use subscript syntax to retrieve or set a value
>   for an index that is outside of an array’s existing bounds, you will
>   trigger a runtime error. However, you can check that an index is valid
>   before using it, by comparing it to the array’s count property. Except
>   when count is 0 (meaning the array is empty), the largest valid index
>   in an array will always be count - 1, because arrays are indexed from
>   zero.

Of course you could always simplify it when possible:

```
var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "logo1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "logo2.png")!
]
```

**edit:** Note that UIImage now has a ["failable" initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17), meaning that it returns an optional. I've updated all the bits of code to reflect this change as well as changes to the array syntax.

Comment: So, as commented on ackStOverflow's response, `UIImage[]()` throws a `Constructive statements on a line must be separated by a ';'` error. Also, those () parenthesis look a lot like a function call. Also this looks a little weird, eh? `UIImage[];()`. Finally, why do I have to use append; why can't I just assign a value to an index?

Comment: @kmiklas `Array<UIImage>` is a Type, you need to instantiate it (using parens): `Array<UIImage>()`, alternatively if you specify the type, you can just assign an array literal (which is the first two examples). `UIImage[]` is just syntactic sugar for `Array<UIImage>`

Comment: @kmiklas added excerpt from docs explaining why you need to append

Comment: For some reason the simplified way you have doesn't work any more.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato `UIImage` is now a failable initializer (meaning it returns an optional) - will update answer

Comment: @Jiaaro when you try to run this code it breaks with the error code `coder : ObjectiveC.NScoder`

Comment: Is there no ```addObject``` method anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the type for logoImages but not creating an instance of that type.

Use `var logoImages = UIImage[]()` which will create a new array for you.

...and then after creating a new empty Array instance, as described in the answer by @Jiaaro you can't use subscripting to add to an empty array

Comment: First, this throws an error, "Constructive statements on a line must be separated by ';'. Xcode wants `UIImage[];()

Comment: Second, I saw this, but those two parenthesis `()` scared me off as a function invocation.

Comment: @kmiklas Sounds like you've got something else going on then.  The line given by ackSt is correct and shouldn't generate errors for you.  Putting a semicolon in where you are is completely changing the meaning.

Comment: @kmiklas make sure you are using `var logoImages = UIImage[]()` which creates a new Array for storing UIImage objects and then assigns it to the logoImages variable (inferring the variable's type from the assignment)... it sounds like you _might_ be incorrectly using a semicolon in place of the equal sign? i.e. `var logoImages: UIImage[]()` which would generate the type of error you describe in your comment

Comment: Honestly, I have nothing else going on. It's the first line in the function, and the first syntax option by Jiaaro below works: var logoImages:UIImage[] = []

Comment: ...also, those two parentheses _are_ a function invocation  :)  they are calling the `init()` method on Array, in the same way you would do it for any other Structure or Class

Answer (score 1):

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"logo.png")    
var logoImages = [image]
```