# How to add images in array

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uiimage

Trying to add images to array, then need to merge four arrays to one array.
What i am trying to do is:

```
var arrFiltersImagesList : NSMutableArray = []
var arrRoomInfoImages = Array<UIImage>()
var arrPropertyInfoImages = Array<UIImage>()
var arrAvailabilityImages = Array<UIImage>()
var arrPreferencesImages = Array<UIImage>()

arrRoomInfoImages += [UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_numberBedrooms_small.png")!]

    arrPropertyInfoImages += [UIImage(named: "ic_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_propertyType_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_numberBedrooms_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_numberBathrooms_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_amenities Copy_small.png")!]

    arrAvailabilityImages += [UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_ensuite_small.png")!]

    arrPreferencesImages += [UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png")!, UIImage(named: "ic_ensuite_small.png")!]

arrFiltersImagesList.addObject(arrRoomInfoImages)
    arrFiltersImagesList.addObject(arrPropertyInfoImages)
    arrFiltersImagesList.addObject(arrAvailabilityImages)
    arrFiltersImagesList.addObject(arrPreferencesImages)
```

Followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172180/swift-creating-an-array-of-uiimage) but doesn't worked at all
output is terrible. Please guide the correct way.
Thanks

Comment: by merge you mean the last array contains the 4 arrays or contains the item of the 4 arrays?

Comment: contains 4 arrays because need to pass the array to tableview number of rows in section.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it by building your arrays into a `let` variable rather than a `var` variable, taking advantage of Swift's ability to infer the type:

```
import UIKit

let arrRoomInfoImages = [
  UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_numberBedrooms_small.png")].flatMap { $0 }

let arrPropertyInfoImages = [
  UIImage(named: "ic_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_propertyType_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_numberBedrooms_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_numberBathrooms_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_amenities Copy_small.png")].flatMap { $0 }

let arrAvailabilityImages = [
  UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_ensuite_small.png")].flatMap { $0 }

let arrPreferencesImages = [
  UIImage(named: "ic_roomType_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_furnished_small.png"),
  UIImage(named: "ic_ensuite_small.png")].flatMap { $0 }

let arrFiltersImagesList = [
  arrRoomInfoImages,
  arrPropertyInfoImages,
  arrAvailabilityImages,
  arrPreferencesImages]
```

Note that I'm not force-unwrapping the return values of the `init` methods. Instead I'm using `flatMap` to cull any `nil` values in the arrays. This is a quick-and-dirty way to handle errors when loading your images, you may want to do something more complicated to make sure any non-loading images are handled properly.

Comment: Why do you `flatMap` the arrays? It should have no effect on one dimensional arrays.

Comment: In addition to reducing the dimension of an array, `flatMap` will also [remove any `nil` values from an array of `Optional` values](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-flatmap/). I'm using it for that effect.

Comment: Ah right! I'm always forgetting about this aspect of it. Good thing, thanks!

Comment: arrays are printing empty

Comment: this is the output: [[], [], [], []]
 of arrFiltersImagesList

Comment: The init method you are calling has this parameter - "name: The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle." Are the images in the app's main bundle?